# Django Allauth Email Verification ( not effective after signup ) .. works after first login

Tags: django, authentication, django-allauth

I'm using allauth in my Django project and it's configured as below to use email for authentication.

- ### allauth configuration*

```
    ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
    ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
    ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
    ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 8
    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
    SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED  = True
```

**Problem is :**

- after signup, i'm directed to Home page without confirming email.
- if it tried to logout and login again, it directs me to  (accounts/confirm-email/) and is now required to confirm my email.

> Note

### user is overridden

```
*(settings.py)*
```

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'home.User'`

     *(models.py)*  
   `class User(AbstractUser):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='user/', blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

i think after signup the user shouldn't be able to login before confirming his email.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
you need to set

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
SIGNUP_REDIRECT_URL
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL
```

At the [E-mail Verification](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html?highlight=confirm#e-mail-verification)
in allauth docs it says

> a verification e-mail is sent pointing to the `allauth.account.views.ConfirmEmailView` view

in that view

```py
    
def get_redirect_url(self):
        return get_adapter(self.request).get_email_confirmation_redirect_url(
            self.request
        )
```

an the content of that function

```py
    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        """
        Returns the default URL to redirect to after logging in.  Note
        that URLs passed explicitly (e.g. by passing along a `next`
        GET parameter) take precedence over the value returned here.
        """
        assert request.user.is_authenticated
        url = getattr(settings, "LOGIN_REDIRECT_URLNAME", None)
        if url:
            warnings.warn(
                "LOGIN_REDIRECT_URLNAME is deprecated, simply"
                " use LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL with a URL name",
                DeprecationWarning,
            )
        else:
            url = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
        return resolve_url(url)
```

which get the redirect url from setting as `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` or whatever you name it such `SIGNUP_REDIRECT_URL` will work with signup and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have enough rep points to comment, so writing this as an answer.

If you're running in dev (ie with (`DEBUG = True`), the email won't actually be sent. You need to check the console and you'll see the text of the email. It will include a url. Ctrl-Click that and it will take you to the confirm-email page. Click confirm, and your user's email address will be verified. You can then try to login for that user and it should work ok.